# How to stop MediaPlayer when the App is Backgrounded in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-mediaplayer, media-player

How can MediaPlayer be **stopped** when the App is **backgrounded**? I see that the MediaPlayer stops when screen rotates. But the MediaPlayed keeps playing while it is backgrounded and a **different App** is run.

```
val current = LocalContext.current
val player1: MediaPlayer = remember {MediaPlayer.create(current, R.raw.music1)}

DisposableEffect(Unit) {
    player1.isLooping = true
    player1.start()
    onDispose {
        player1.stop()
    }
}
```

I tried adding MediaPlayer in a class which was life cycle aware. This can be controlled from compose. But the functions "onPause" and "onStop" do not stop the MediaPlayer.

class ExampleClass(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application),
DefaultLifecycleObserver {

```
private var player: MediaPlayer? = null

fun toggleOn(application: Application) {
    if (player == null) {
       player = MediaPlayer.create(application, R.raw.music1)
    }
    player!!.start()
}

fun toggleOff() {
    player!!.pause()
}



override fun onPause(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
    super.onPause(owner)
    toggleOff()
}

override fun onStop(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
    super.onStop(owner)
    toggleOff()
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Use `LifecycleOwner` and `LauchedEffect`

```kotlin
    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
    DisposableEffect(key1 = lifecycleOwner) {
        val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
            if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME) {
                player.start()
            } else if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP) {
                player.stop()
            }
        }

        // Add the observer to the lifecycle
        lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(observer)

        // When the effect leaves the Composition, remove the observer
        onDispose {
            lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }
```

A similar sample: [here](https://github.com/FunnySaltyFish/FunnyTranslation/blob/1c9f352c2addceaee31ed9b87c552e64c9941010/translate/src/main/java/com/funny/translation/translate/ui/main/CameraCapture.kt#L113)

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could vote the answer :)

Comment: I am not allowed to, because I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote

Comment: Got it. Then thank you for your approvement, and that's enough.